# Vue staging build creates a development build instead of production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode):

> vue-cli-service build --mode staging builds a production app in
> staging mode, using .env, .env.staging and .env.staging.local if they
> are present.

package.json

```
"buildStaging": "vue-cli-service build --mode staging",
```

.env.staging

```
VUE_APP_LOG_PRODUCTION_TIP=true
```

Then

```
>npm run buildStaging
> between-us-drivers@0.1.0 buildStaging C:\dev\mezinamiridici\spa
> vue-cli-service build --mode staging
/  Building for staging...
```

And the result is:

```
171 650 admin-chunk.js
112 650 admin-chunk.js.map
6 156 774 app.js
6 008 903 app.js.map
1 517 776 content-chunk.js
1 434 561 content-chunk.js.map
477 276 user-chunk.js
425 751 user-chunk.js.map
```

Why is there the development build instead of production build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your staging to make a production build you'll need to specify it via `NODE_ENV` in `.env.staging`:

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_LOG_PRODUCTION_TIP=true
```

This is hinted at, but not highlighted in [the documentation example for staging](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode):

> The app is built as a production app because of the `NODE_ENV`, but in the staging version, `process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE` is overwritten with a different value

The core behavior is covered slightly earlier in [the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes):

> When running `vue-cli-service`, *[...]* `NODE_ENV` will be set to `"production"` in production mode, `"test"` in test mode, and defaults to `"development"` otherwise.

Comment: Well, this part of documentation is IMHO quite cryptic. Thank you.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I agree, it is covered at the start of the doc, but could be highlighted in that bit as well. I've updated the answer with the generic case, too.